# Creating a subsite/web via the Sharepoint Web Serivces - is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to create/add a Sharepoint subsite on an existing site collection through the web service api (as oppposed to the object model or RPC), but I see no clear way on any of the Admin.asmx, Webs.asmx, Site.asmx, or Sites.asmx services to do so.

I can see ways to create a full site collection, lists, and list items, but not to create a subsite on an existing site collection.

Can someone please confirm whether or not there is a way on the out-of-the-box sharepoint web services to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's exceedingly (well, maybe not exceedingly) easy to create your own SharePoint-aware web service.  If the existing API isn't sufficient to meet your needs, then you might consider rolling your own to give you more domain-specific functionality.  I found this MSDN article to be pretty helpful, and I rolled up the WSDL modifications into a post-build event to simplify the edit-build-deploy process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have googled around and found these 2 references

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/47d63dbf-3740-4e97-bc5c-17c39ef7b174/

http://community.officesharepointpro.com/forums/post/16971.aspx